# Encoding Hell - \u2019 won't map

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, python-requests

I know this type of question has been beaten to death.  I've read everything I can find, I understand the problem (or at least think I do), and I still can't figure out what's going on here.  This problem is recurring and driving me insane.

One example is scraping federal holidays from:
[https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/snow-dismissal-procedures/federal-holidays/'](https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/snow-dismissal-procedures/federal-holidays/)

If I try to print table data text, sublime chokes (no output), and powershell gives me an encoding error (can't encode \2019 - which is a right apostrophe).  The headers on the website say UTF-8, which requests correctly detects and uses as the encoding (`requests.get(url).encoding`), so I'm a bit at a loss.  While I can understand powershell failing since it uses a narrower unicode standard (cp437 IIRC), I don't understand sublime displaying no output since it defaults to UTF-8 afaik.

Here is a quick simple example, where base_url is the main URL listed above (or any of the subsequent years once you're on the source page).  FWIW I have these problems almost exclusively on Windows, which I have to use for work.

```
def get_year(url):
    source = requests.get(url,proxies=proxies)
    doc = html.fromstring(source.text)
    td=doc.xpath('//td/text()') 
    return td

print(get_year(base_url))
```

Comment: You're right, anything encoding to UTF-8 should always succeed. Can you show the full error stack?

Comment: Have you tried changing the encoding of the request answer? i.e., `source.encoding = 'utf-8'`

Comment: If you encode the string yourself you can set "ignore" or "replace" error policies. I don't know how to change the encoder for `print`, but a (likely lame but functional) solution may be `print(get_year(base_url).encode(sys.stdout.encoding,errors='replace').decode(sys.stdout.encoding))`.

Comment: @Andfoy yes - but it doesn't matter because requests already set the encoding to utf-8 by default (it makes a guess based on http headers, which are utf-8 for that site). Mark Ransom -  There is no error in sublime, it just finishes with empty space. For powershell the error is that the coded can't encode \u2019.

Comment: @tdelaney So this is interesting ... I still get empty display in Sublime, but to powershell it correctly prints replacing the offending \u2019 with '?', as it should.

Comment: My guess is that your problem is with decoding the unicode character when you try to print. Windows does have unicode code pages but they aren't usually set when installing and are tricky to change to on a running system (imagine all the data written to your code page suddenly not working any more). You can change to utf-8 for a console session by running `chcp 65001`. Try that, then run sublime and see if everybody is happy.

Comment: @tdelaney - bad idea. `chcp 65001` is not really UTF-8. If you want python to correctly print to Windows console, use https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console

Comment: Voting to close. A more succinct question is asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361206/sublime-will-not-print-certain-unicode-chars-on-windows/34363143?noredirect=1#comment56470598_34363143

Error is IDE / Console specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here what I did:

```
import urllib

url = 'https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/snow-dismissal-procedures/federal-holidays/'

data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
udata = unicode(data,'utf-8')
```

**EDIT BEGIN**

After complaints about using `urllib`, the same thing with `requests`, with no difference, of course:

```
source = requests.get(url)
udata = source.text
```

**EDIT END**

There are no encoding errors or any other problems.
I searched for non-ASCII characters. There is only one: `\xA0` at index `53513`.

There is no `\2019` character there! However, there is `&rsquo;`, which translates to the same.

So, it seems that one of the libraries you are using has converted `&rsquo;` to `\2019`, but with wrong encoding, thus creating an invalid string. Later on, it crashed in some other place. All of that happened *after downloading*. You should track what happens with downloaded data to see which function did that. Then see what its documentation says about that.

**EDIT 2 BEGIN**

Following the original code al the way through, I came to the place where the last line `print(get_year(base_url))` raises an exception.

Inspecting that, it appears that, as presumed above, `lxml` converted `&rsquo;` to `\2019`, so we have:

```
>>> s = get_year(base_url)[1]
>>> s
u'New Year\u2019s Day'
```

Printing that to the console fails if the console's encoding does not support `\u2019` character. On windows, that is often the case.

**EDIT 2 END**

Comment: On what type of machine did you test? Was it a windows command prompt with a Windows code page instead of utf-8? You can check by `print(sys.stdout.encoding)`.

Comment: The question is very specific about using `requests`, why are you trying to duplicate the problem using `urllib`?

Comment: @MarkRansom I edited my answer. There is no difference with `requests`.

Comment: @tdelaney I used python console started from windows console, on windos 7, `sys.stdout.encoding` is `cp852`. Do you really think it makes a difference?

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the downvote. It probably has something to do with my answer being incorrect or not related to the question?

Comment: I think the problem is that the character doesn't decode in his code page when trying to print data so which cp is there does make a difference. I wasn't the downvoter, btw, but I don't have a windows machine handy to check up on what is going on.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, you were right. In my last edit, I came to that same conclusion. It was not clear to me from the question at start that the problems occurred at `print` time, I assumed it was something before that. BTW the downvote comment was a broadcast, not directed at you ;)

Comment: Marking this correct since it's the one answer posted and we all seem to be in agreement, although I still don't know why sublime won't print considering it should default to UTF?  Thanks @tdelaney also for your help.

Comment: @Solaxun I tried with sublime, but could not reproduce the problem. I suggest opening a new simple question with "sublime" and "python" tags, asking why this fails to show up in output: `print u'New Year\u2019s Day'`. That does not show up, am I right? And this works: `print 1234`, right?

Comment: That is exactly correct.  I'll open a new question.  This only happens on my windows machine (tried last night on my mac, no issues).