# Sublime will not print certain unicode chars on windows

Tags: python, unicode, sublimetext3

Been having some issues lately on my work machine (windows), where printing certain Unicode characters displays nothing.  No error, just the script finishes and there is empty space in the build section.

As an example:

```
print(u'New Year\u2019s Day')
```

> [Finished in 0.2s]

Not sure why this is happening as the default encoding is utf-8 in sublime as far as i know, and \u2019 is very clearly a valid utf-8 character.

As requested... sublime config:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/python.exe","$file"],
    "selector":"source.py"
}
```

Comment: try passing PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8" as an env option. Please provide your build config if this does not fix it.

Comment: I set that variable in CMD and it did nothing.  I set it at a user level and not system, (admin issues) but python is locally installed anyhow so shouldn't matter.  What do you mean specifically by build config?  The sublime build config?  Nothing remarkable there...

Comment: `env` is an option to exec in Sublime build system. See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` environment in your build config:

```
{
   "cmd": ["C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/python.exe","$file"],
   "selector":"source.py",
   "env": { 'PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8" }
}
```

Comment: Wow can't believe that is necessary but it totally worked.  Thanks!

Comment: I prefer Pydev in Eclipse or PyCharm, which don't have these kind of problems :)